# What is another term for a deception operation?

Tags: armed-conflict, terminology

Like we have the term False Flag for covert operations to put blame for an event on a third party, is there any term for deception covert operations that are meant to fool the opponent? I am looking specifically in the context of special/covert operations.

Comment: One party has a secret that needs protection. It may be position of army units or a breakthrough in crytography. The intent of the operation would be to fool allies, enemies or neutral parties about  these capabilities. An example that comes to mind is operation mincemeat during WW2.

Comment: Word requests are generally asked at one of the English Language sites (ELU, ELL).  The word is *feint*.

Comment: I took my liberty to edit "opposition" to "opponent" which might be a better word choice here.

Comment: Another applicable term would be *stalking horse*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be *[Diversion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diversion)*

> 3: an attack or feint that draws the attention and force of an enemy from the point of the principal operation
>    *You create **a diversion** while I sneak inside the building.*